# Unable to connect to MongoDB Replica Set using public IP addresses

Tags: mongodb, networking, mongodb-replica-set

I have configured a three-node replica set in MongoDB; replication is in sync.

I am able to connect to each server individually, and using each server's private IP address I can to connect to the replica set like this:

> mongo --host rs0/10.X.X.X:27017,10.X.X.X:27017,10.X.X.X:27017 -u root -p abc123 --authenticationDatabase admin

But when I try to connect to the replica set using the servers' public IP addresses, like this:

> mongo --host rs0/52.X.X.X:27017,52.X.X.X:27017,52.X.X.X:27017 -u root -p abc123 --authenticationDatabase admin

I get an error: "*No primary detected for set rs0*".

Comment: This really should be asked on [dba,stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is for questions and answers relating to database administration and configuration. StackOverflow is for :"programming" based questions, of which this is not. Please move your post to the appropriate site instead of posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect to the replica set, you should use the *same addresses* (ip addresses or host names) as the nodes use for each other in the replica set configuration. For replica set deployment, you need to:

> [Ensure that network traffic can pass between all members of the set and all clients in the network securely and efficiently.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#connectivity)

In practice, it is best *not* to configure your replica set using public ip addresses; it is more secure to use the private ip addresses, which helps ensure that your database can only receive connections from authorised locations.

Answer (score 0):

this might be one of the reason.

You should add all 3 servers public IP in to the bind ip values in all 3 servers /etc/mongod.conf

if your are using AWS, you need to allow all this IP for inbound access to another server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for responses,
It needed to configure replica with public Ips in rs.config